# POWER_MODE_IDLE wake on any input change?

Tags: interrupt, sleep

I want to be able to put an Arduino to "sleep" but I want it to immediately resume if any panel tactile buttons are pressed.

The purpose is to try to minimize any digital noise in an nearby high gain analog circuit.

My guess at this point is that I want to put the Arduino into POWER_MODE_IDLE but it is less clear to me the best way to wake up.

How can I instantly wake up from POWER_MODE_ILDE if any input changes? I don't want to have to hold down a button or even use a specific input. Is there a "catch-all" interrupt that will react immedately to a change on any or on a large set of inputs?

Comment: Look for "pin change interrupts" (PCINT).

Answer (score 1):

As I mention on my [page about interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) you can use pin-change interrupts on the Atmega328P to wake from the deepest sleep mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN).

Example code:

```C++
#include <avr/sleep.h>

const byte LEDLOOP = 8;
const byte LEDWAKE = 9;

ISR (PCINT1_vect)
 {
 // handle pin change interrupt for A0 to A5 here

 // toggle LED
 digitalWrite (LEDWAKE, !digitalRead (LEDWAKE));
 }  // end of PCINT1_vect

void setup () 
  {
  pinMode (LEDWAKE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LEDLOOP, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (A0, HIGH);  // enable pull-up

  // pin change interrupt
  PCMSK1 |= bit (PCINT8);  // want pin A0
  PCIFR  |= bit (PCIF1);   // clear any outstanding interrupts
  PCICR  |= bit (PCIE1);   // enable pin change interrupts for A0 to A5

  }  // end of setup

void loop () 
{

  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);  
  sleep_mode ();  

  // flash to indicate we got out of sleep
  digitalWrite (LEDLOOP, HIGH);
  delay (100);
  digitalWrite (LEDLOOP, LOW);
  delay (100);

  } // end of loop
```

This has the advantage of consuming very little power while asleep, and also waking on any pin (of an Atmega328P).

Running on 5V at 25°C you should only consume around 150 nA of current while asleep (on a "bare bones" board without USB chip, voltage regulator or power LEDs).

Other sleep modes may use more power but wake more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino can only be woken from sleep by a change on pins 2 and/or 3.

> On the hardware front, the Arduino is equipped with two interrupt
>   ports: digital pin 2 and 3. So the Arduino can sense those pins for an
>   event to wake up and resume execution of code.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode

However, the datasheet indicates that any pin can be used:

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf Section 17. EXINT - External Interrupts

> The External Interrupts are triggered by the INT pins or any of the PCINT pins. 
>   [...]
>   The Pin Change Interrupt Request 2 (PCI2) will trigger if any enabled 
>   PCINT[23:16] pin toggles. The Pin Change Interrupt Request 1 (PCI1)
>   will trigger if any enabled PCINT[14:8] pin toggles. The Pin Change
>   Interrupt Request 0 (PCI0) will trigger if any enabled PCINT[7:0] pin
>   toggles. The PCMSK2, PCMSK1 and
>   PCMSK0 Registers control which pins contribute to the pin change
>   interrupts.

Comment: Pin change interrupts can be used as well. Even for deeper sleep modes with disabled IO clock or with stopped oscillator.